# How to take value by a edited fild in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my database: "Discount". Here I have 3 columns, for example: price1, price2, price3, I want to take one of these values, but this depends on another select statement:

Select price(here I want to do a select from another table, that return 1,2,3)
from Discount

Is there a possibility to do this select or I must to this with a case statement?

thank you for help

Comment: You are having this problem because your table is not well designed. It would be much simpler with an extra column "DiscountType" and only one "Price" column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using dynamic query as below

```
declare @sql nvarcahr(max)
set @sql = 'select price'+select number from other query as varchar(2)+' from Discount'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

1. looks like case is the best option.
2. You may also make dynamic sql, first, get the number from "another table", then construct your sql statement at runtime and execute.
3. you can do it without case:

   ```
   with t2(id) as 
   (select 'price' || value as id from "another table")
   select price1 as price from discount, t2
   where t2.id = 1
   union all
   select price2 from discount, t2
   where t2.id = 2
   union all
   select price3 from discount, t2
   where t2.id = 3
   ```